# Why can't I change the text of an UNANSWERED question?

Tags: discussion

[How useful is Hong Kong Human Rights and Democracy Act of 2019 to HK protesters?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/47913/28700) is open, and has no answers.

[Parliament v. Crown in Parliament](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/50037/28700), [Parliament v. Queen in Parliament](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/50038/28700) were closed as duplicates, and had no answers.

I changed them to different questions, but Phillip moderator rolled back.
Rather than posting new questions, why can't I change them to different questions? It's a waste of space and time for people and me to keep seeing [Duplicate].

Comment: If you don't want those old questions around, and you want to ask something else, why not just delete the old ones and post the new ones separately?

Answer (score 10):

A question should not be changed to be about something completely different.

If you think that could be edited so the reason why it was closed no longer applies, please edit it. But do so in a way which stays faithful to the original question. Don't turn it into a question about a completely different subject.

If you want to give up on the question, please delete it.

Answer (score 5):

An obvious reason not do something like this, i.e. change the topic to something completely unrelated (even when there are no answers) is that one can make a problematic topic appear to have been upvoted, or vice-versa, make some uncontroversial question appear to have been heavily downvoted if one radically changes the topic after the votes came in.